# Mockito.mockConstruction does not return the mocked object

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I don't want to use powermock anymore. Because junit5 started mocking static classes. So i am trying to get rid of powermock methods.

As you know, you can create an instance of a class with whenNew keyword. So i decided to use " mockConstruction " . But mockConstruction does not return the mocked object. It doesn't go inside the try block.

This is my BeforeEach method:

```
 @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        partUnlinkService =
            spy(new PartVideoUnlinkService(part1, part2,
                part3));
    }
```

This is my test method:

```
  @Test
    void shouldThrowException() throws Exception {
        //given
        UrlLinkDto urlLinkDto =
            UrlPartLinkDto.builder().callId("333").videoId("5555544").build();
        ArgumentCaptor<UrlPartLinkDto> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UrlPartLinkDto.class);
        //when
        try (MockedConstruction<ObjectMapper> ignoredVariable = mockConstruction(ObjectMapper.class,
            (objectMapper, context) -> {
                //then
                partUnlinkService.unlink(urlLinkDto, false);
                verify(partLogCheckService, times(1)).checkForExistingVideo(
                    urlLinkDto.getVideoId());
                verify(objectMapper, times(1)).writeValueAsString(argumentCaptor.capture());
                Throwable throwable =
                    catchThrowable(() -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(argumentCaptor.capture()));
                assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(JsonProcessingException.class);
            })) {
        } 
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access mocks that were created during the instantiation of your objects via [MockedConstruction.constructed()](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockedConstruction.html) method. It represents a collection of mocks that are created after each constructor's execution. If your object will be instantiated 3 times `MockedConstruction<T>.constructed()` will return 3 different mock objects for each instantiation.

According to documentation `MockedConstruction<T>`

> Represents a mock of any object construction of the represented type.
> Within the scope of the mocked construction, the invocation of any
> interceptor will generate a mock which will be prepared as specified
> when generating this scope. The mock can also be received via this
> instance.

Simple implementation with comments below shows how to get mocks from `MockedConstruction` and verify them:

```java
public class A {
    private final String test;

    public A(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String check() {
        return "checked " + this.test;
    }
}

public class TestService {
    public String purchaseProduct(String param) {
        A a = new A(param);
        return a.check();
    }
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedConstruction;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ConstructorMockTest {
    private MockedConstruction<A> mockAController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beginTest() {
        //create mock controller for all constructors of the given class
        mockAController = Mockito.mockConstruction(A.class,
                (mock, context) -> {
                    //implement initializer for mock. Set return value for object A mock methods
                    when(mock.check()).thenReturn(" Constructor Mock A ");
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //each instantiation of class A will return new mock, which initialized by initializer from beginTest method
        //new mock will be stored to mockAController.constructed() collection of mocks
        A aObject = new A("test");
        //ensure that method check() returns mocked value
        Assertions.assertEquals(aObject.check(), " Constructor Mock A ");
        //get just created mock for class A from controller. It will be first element of mockAController.constructed() collection
        A aMock = mockAController.constructed().get(0);
        //ensure that we get correct mock from mock controller, that it is equal from new created object
        Assertions.assertEquals(aMock, aObject);
        //verify that check method was executed on Mock
        verify(aMock, times(1)).check();

        //create new A object, new mock created and stored to mockAController.constructed()
        A aObject2 = new A("test");
        //ensure that method check() returns mocked value
        Assertions.assertEquals(aObject2.check(), " Constructor Mock A ");
        //get just created mock for class A from controller, it will be second object from constructed collection
        A aMock2 = mockAController.constructed().get(1);
        //ensure that we get correct mock from mock controller, that it is equal from just created A object
        Assertions.assertEquals(aObject2, aMock2);
        //verify that check method was executed on Mock
        verify(aMock2, times(1)).check();

        //Example of testing service which creates A object
        TestService service = new TestService();
        String serviceResult = service.purchaseProduct("test");
        //ensure that service returned value  from A mock
        Assertions.assertEquals(serviceResult, " Constructor Mock A ");
        //get just created mock for class A from controller, it will be third object from constructed collection
        A aMock3 = mockAController.constructed().get(2);
        //verify that check method was executed on Mock
        verify(aMock3, times(1)).check();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void endTest() {
        mockAController.close();
    }
}
```

Let's rewrite your test. I do not have the full code, but I will try to create an example with comments:

```java
    @Test
    void shouldThrowException() throws Exception {
        //given
        UrlLinkDto urlLinkDto =
                UrlPartLinkDto.builder().callId("333").videoId("5555544").build();
        ArgumentCaptor<UrlPartLinkDto> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UrlPartLinkDto.class);

        try (MockedConstruction<ObjectMapper> objectMapperMockedConstruction = mockConstruction(ObjectMapper.class,
                (objectMapper, context) -> {
                     //initialize ObjectMapper mock to throw exception when argumentCaptor will come to writeValueAsString method
                    doThrow(JsonProcessingException.class).when(objectMapper).writeValueAsString(argumentCaptor.capture());
                })) {

            //execute service for testing and catch exception
            Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> partUnlinkService.unlink(urlLinkDto, false));

            //verify that inner service was executed
            verify(partLogCheckService, times(1)).checkForExistingVideo(urlLinkDto.getVideoId());

            //verify that ObjectMapper was instantiated
            Assertions.assertEquals(1, objectMapperMockedConstruction.constructed().size());
            //get mock of ObjectMapper which was instantiated during service execution
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapperMockedConstruction.constructed().get(0);
            //verify that writeValueAsString was executed
            verify(objectMapper, times(1)).writeValueAsString(argumentCaptor.capture());

            //check that exception is correct
            assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(JsonProcessingException.class);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same question as you, hope someone can solve our problem.

In my case, I also want to got a return object like PowerMock.whenNew().withArguments().thenReturn(someThing), I try a lot of times but it failed.
I think mockConstruction just only can mock their behavior, can't verify their result like powerMock, and I couldn't find any articles or answers.
below is my post link :

[Junit 5 use mockConstruction().withSetting().useConstructor() instead of PowerMock.whenNew().withArguments()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394231/junit-5-use-mockconstruction-withsetting-useconstructor-instead-of-powermo)